# In laravel how to move Image file from one folder to another folder

Tags: php, forms, image, laravel, move

I have many image file in a folder. I have done showing all image file in a blade file in html form. I want to choose a image file to upload a database table field. I have done this process but I can't move that chosen image file move one folder to another folder and I want to do that after moving this image file, all the image file remove from this folder. please help me

Comment: I can help you, please share your code, errors ?

Comment: _I can't move that chosen image_ can you explain why ?

Comment: in some hosting service on cpanel that they try to host laravel the public_path method related to folder in top priority of cpanel that users cant access to them. so we need to change path to another folder or move after move

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine for moving file from one **folder to another**:

```
 $move = File::move($old_path, $new_path);
```

You can use this format for getting **path_name**:

```
$path =  public_path().'/img/logo/'. $yourFileName;
```

If you want the action to be done on base folder then use `base_path()` instead of `public_path()`

Comment: OP said _I can't move that chosen image_ . Without knowing reason it difficult to say what would be the solution. `Code` `Permission` or `Path` anything would be the reason.

Comment: Now I want to delete all image file from old path. How can I do it?

Comment: The file should be deleted after being moved from one folder to another but if that doesn't happen you can use this syntax: `$delete   =  File::delete($old_path);`